# How can I see the list of questions that were removed by a mod from the list of hot network questions on a given SE website?

Tags: support, data-explorer, moderation, hot-questions

How can I see the list of questions that were manually removed (= removed by a mod) from the list of hot network questions on a given SE website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do so using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1612210/hnq-list-with-moderator-removed-questions-only).

This should give you a list of all moderator-removed hot network questions only, along with other details (date and time of removal, number of hours on the HNQ list, etc.).

Here is an example query with a list of questions from English Language & Usage that were manually removed by moderators in the past 360 days:

[image]

Comment: Though of course mods can remove questions without using the removal tool, by simply closing (or deleting!) the question.

Comment: @Laurel: Unfortunately, there's no record of a question being removed from the HNQ list (because of it being closed) in the timeline of the question... It's only recorded when a question is removed using the removal tool.

Comment: I'll have a look whether I can update my HNQ scraper data, which keeps track of how long questions actually remain in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Another [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/1043136/questions-removed-from-hnq-list) to list questions that were manually removed (= removed by a mod) from the list of hot network questions on a given SE website, by [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel):

```sql
SELECT h53.PostId AS [Post Link],
  h52.CreationDate AS [Became hot],
  h53.CreationDate AS [Removed],
  h53.UserId AS [User Link],
  'site://posts/' + CAST(h53.PostId AS NVARCHAR) + '/revisions|Revisions'
  FROM PostHistory AS h53
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PostHistory AS h52
    ON h52.PostId = h53.PostId
   AND h52.PostHistoryTypeId = 52 -- became HNQ
  WHERE h53.PostHistoryTypeId = 53 -- removed from HNQ
  ORDER BY h53.CreationDate DESC
```

This [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/1043249/questions-removed-from-hnq-list) by an anonymous  user adds to the list all other HNQs:

```sql
SELECT h52.PostId AS [Post Link],
  h52.CreationDate AS [Became hot],
  h53.CreationDate AS [Removed],
  h53.UserId AS [User Link],
  'site://posts/' + CAST(h52.PostId AS NVARCHAR) + '/revisions|Revisions'
  FROM PostHistory AS h52
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PostHistory AS h53
    ON h52.PostId = h53.PostId
   AND h53.PostHistoryTypeId = 53 -- removed from HNQ
 WHERE h52.PostHistoryTypeId = 52 -- became HNQ
  ORDER BY h52.CreationDate DESC
```